# Помощь в написании задержки в командах бота на пайтон

Tags: python, aiogram, mongodb, бот, pymongo

Библиотеки в коде

---

1. *PyMongo*
2. *DateTime*

---

Хочу что-бы при вводе первой команды она выполнялась, а при вводе 2-ой но не подождав 5и сек выведется текст сколько осталось ждать и после того как пройдёт 5 сек можно будет ещё раз выполнить команду, для базы данных используется mongodb.

---

Код который получилось написать *(без бота)*

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime



current_time = datetime.now()

user_id = 0

if collection.count_documents({"_id": user_id}) == 0:
    post = [
        {
            "_id": user_id,
            "datetime": datetime.now()
        }
    ]
    collection.insert_many(post)

get_dt = collection.find_one({"_id": user_id})["datetime"]
delta_seconds = (datetime.now() - get_dt).total_seconds()
collection.update_one({"_id": user_id}, {"$set": {"datetime": current_time}})

if delta_seconds < 5:
    print(f"Подождите {delta_seconds} секунд перед выполнение этой команды")
else:
    print("Получено")
    collection.update_one({"_id": user_id}, {"$set": {"datetime": datetime.now()}})
```

***P.S.** В этом коде не очень работает всё правильно*

Comment: Что-то я не вижу код бота

Comment: Не стал сюда кидать код бота, вместо можно использовать input()

Comment: Боюсь это так не работает.

Comment: просто обернуть всё функцией в конце функции ставить задержку